# How to Handle Exceptions Caused by Holidays and Weekends in Python

Tags: python, date, exception

I'm using an [API](https://addisonlynch.github.io/iexfinance/stable/index.html) to lookup historical stock market prices for a given company on the last day of each month. The problem is that the last day can sometimes fall on a weekend or holiday, in which case the API returns a `KeyError`. I've tried using an exception to handle this by adding `n` number to the date to get the next-closest valid one, but this is not foolproof.

Here is my existing code:

```
import os
from iexfinance.stocks import get_historical_data
import iexfinance
import pandas as pd

# Set API Keys
os.environ['IEX_API_VERSION'] = 'iexcloud-sandbox'
os.environ['IEX_TOKEN'] = 'Tsk_5798c0ab124d49639bb1575b322841c4'

stocks = ['AMZN', 'FDX', 'XXXXX', 'BAC', 'COST']
date = "20191130"

for stock in stocks:

    try:
        price_df = get_historical_data(stock, date, close_only=True,output_format='pandas')
        price = price_df['close'].values[0]
        print(price)
    except KeyError:
        date = str(int(date) - 1)
        price_df = get_historical_data(stock, date, close_only=True, output_format='pandas')
        price = price_df['close'].values[0]
        print(price)
    except iexfinance.utils.exceptions.IEXQueryError:
        print(stock + " is not a valid company")
```

But if you change `date = "20160131"`, then you get a `KeyError` again.

So is there a simple way to handle these exceptions and get the next-valid date?

*Note that the API Key is public and for sandbox purposes, so feel free to use*

Comment: would it make sense to put this code in a function, and recursively call itself with date-1 until it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
def get_prices(stocks, date):
    for stock in stocks:
        try:
            price_df = get_historical_data(stock, date, close_only=True,output_format='pandas')
            price = price_df['close'].values[0]
            print(stock + " was @ $" + str(price) + " on " + str(date))
        except KeyError:
            return get_prices(stocks, date = str(int(date) - 1))
            print(stock + " was @ $" + str(price) + " on " + str(date))
        except iexfinance.utils.exceptions.IEXQueryError:
            print(stock + " is not a valid company")
```